# Zend Framework - How can i translate and switch the language from right to left

Tags: php, jquery, zend-framework, arabic

How can i regularise my right to left language where it is Arabic language. So it must start from right to left including all scroll bar, input box, upload whole layout is actually required to be shown as right to left.

## This is my layout:

```
<?= $this->doctype();// xhtml = strict ?>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <?php echo $this->headTitle(); ?>
    <?php echo $this->headMeta(); ?>
    <?php echo $this->headScript(); ?>
    <?php echo $this->headLink()->prependStylesheet('/css/production.css'); ?>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/img/pageicon.png" type="image/x-icon" />
    <link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="We care Arab Page"      href="/rss.xml" />
</head>
<body>
!!!!!! everything need right to left, where default page is english (left to right).!!!!!
</body>
</html>
```

Please advise ? :)

Thanks & Regards

## Follow up:

- $this->view->headMeta()->appendName('Language','en');
  This is not related to DIR
- http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/struct/dirlang.html
  This is a solution actually
- It works

  < html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="ar" dir="RTL" >
- ZF-> How do you assign it from MVC controller ?

  < html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="ar" dir=< ?= $this->rtl; ? > > ???
- tried 2 suggestion

  < body style="direction:rtl;" >
  OR
  < html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="ar" dir="RTL" >

Dont see any differences for direction changing. Image does not flip, all the rest flip exactly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do most of my web sites in arabic language and i don't have to depend in `dir="RTL"` all the time 
for example : 
on every project i work with ,

1. i use 960 grid + jQuery + ZF
2. I used  to float most of my element
   to the right  for `div ,  p  , table
   , em ,    h1 ... h6 ,  form input` 
   and some times i add style for p tag
   like this : `directtion:RTL` to make
   thing align correctly
3. I am used to set chartset for any
   part of the application to `UTF8` form the view to the database ... etc

hopefully i didn't miss any thing 
and Good luck

**update**

let's take the [facebook.com](http://facebook.com) arabic page as an example , it doesn't have code like yours

`< html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="ar" dir="RTL" >`  ,

the body tage has style for `direction:RTL`  you would see some of the form elements flipped

**but notice the world image , it didn't flip to the left** but in your case all the element would flip if you removed this `dir='rtl'` attribute

what i meant to say : control your element on the page

Comment: Now your comments creating more confusion. Above example does actually all the RTL. Why do you require explicitly 1,2,3 steps ? And how come utf8 is related to RTL ?

Comment: No utf-8 doesn't have any relation to RTL , I use UTF-8 to save and view both arabic & non arabic letter correctly

Comment: regarding your layout over , you would have problem if you had text with two languages (arabic + english )

Comment: 12 Errors, because they dont know what they are doing ex: http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Far-ar.facebook.com%2F&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0    you are saying css to apply ex: body { direction: rtl; }  /* Which means righ to left inside body tag */ but i am saying html attribute you can also do that.

Comment: And about the image, how can you then flip it ? Do you have fliper in Dojo ?

Comment: I just now applied dir=rtl with firefox->arabic settings. After rendering it didnt fliped my logo (which is in your case the world logo).

Comment: Then i removed the html dir=rtl and applied this now: <body style="direction: rtl;">  which is same in result, just same.

Comment: Thanks a lot, OK, i found it why you think UTF-8 + CSS + Other methods are best for this. ex: <body style="direction: rtl; unicode-bidi: bidi-override;" >

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure it's the best way to do it, but i would first set an application wide locale to the corresponding language/region (like en_US or any other that suits your needs). I would then provide the corresponding translation files to fit all the availables languages and then set a new css to reflect the right-to-left reading direction and reorganize the page layout.

The changes won't occur magically in the browser, even if you set an other language. Only the charset will adapt to your locale.

Comment: you still have to do a lot of work and the layout won't flip because the reading direction change